# qtip - distinct results on distinct table rows

Tags: jquery

I have table with few rows, after use hover mouse over row I want to display qtip ( http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/#create ) tooltip. How can I refer to some row id in function, where I define displayed content:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.qtip').qtip({
           content:  $(this)  <-- this don't work
        });
});
```

I have tables with rows like this:

```
 <td class="qtip" id="pic-<?php echo $item->product_id; ?>">
```

I want to display row id in tooltip. (for example pic-1232)

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I would like the qTip to work on <tr> elements if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $(this).attr('id') as the content of the qtip plugin. 
BTW it is not the row id but the cell id as you get the id of the td element.

@PKKid set the class on your tr element and it will work on the whole row.